# Storybool could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I want to add components to storybook.
After I've tried to add component Header to storybook,I'had this problem.
But why I have this problem and what do I need to add to fix it?
I've provider in index.tsx.
I've tried to add ProviderDecorator for story but it'has not helped me.

```
root.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <ErrorBoundary>
                <ThemeProvider>
                    <App />
                </ThemeProvider>
            </ErrorBoundary>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,
);
```

[image]

Component Header

```
    interface HeaderProps {
        className?: string,
    }
    const Header:FC<HeaderProps> = (props) => {
        const { className } = props;
        const { t, i18n } = useTranslation('header');
        const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
        const { theme, toggleTheme } = useTheme();
    
        const { location } = useAppSelector((state) => state.Location);
        const { addLocationPage } = locationSliceActions;
        const pageLocation = useLocation();
        useEffect(() => {
            dispatch(addLocationPage(pageLocation));
        }, [pageLocation]);
    
        const { stateLoginFormPopup } = useAppSelector((state) => state.statePopup);
        const { changeStateLoginFormPopup } = statePopupSliceActions;
        const openLoginFormPopup = React.useCallback(() => {
            dispatch(changeStateLoginFormPopup(true));
        }, []);
    
        return (
            <div className={classNames(cls.Header, {}, [className, 'header__container-big', cls[i18n.language], cls[theme]])}>
                <div className={cls.center_block}>
                    <Logotype
                        theme={theme}
                    />
                    <NavBar />
                    <div className={cls.coverButton}>
                        <Button
                            theme={theme}
                            onClick={openLoginFormPopup}
                        >
                            <Profile
                                className="svg_profile"
                            />
                            {t('Кнопка входа')}
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <LoginModal />
            </div>
        );
    };
    
    export default Header;
```

Component header.story.
Here I tried to add decorator with provider.

```
    const meta = {
        title: 'page/Header', 
        component: Header,
        decorators: [
            StyleDecorator,
            ThemeDecorator('dark_theme'),

        ],
    } satisfies Meta<typeof Header>;
    
    export default meta;
    type Story = StoryObj<typeof meta>;
    
    export const HeaderLight: Story = {
        args: {},
    };
    
    export const HeaderDark: Story = {
        args: {},
    };
```

Answer (score 3):

I've written like this and it's working

```
const meta = {
    title: 'page/Header', // тут меняем путь
    component: Header,
    decorators: [
        StyleDecorator,
        ThemeDecorator('dark_theme'),
        (Story) => (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Story />
                </BrowserRouter>
            </Provider>
        ),
    ],
} satisfies Meta<typeof Header>;
```